# Strange strings comparison in Unix sort

Tags: linux, sorting, ubuntu

I was playing with `sort` in Ubuntu and saw a strange thing:
Sorting (`sort test.txt`):

```
d
auto_design
tst
auto_tuning
autosport
```

Gives:

```
auto_design
autosport
auto_tuning
d
tst
```

But sorting

```
d
auto_design
auto_tuning
autoaport
```

Gives

```
autoaport
auto_design
auto_tuning
d
tst
```

If it sorts lexicographical why "a", "b", "c" are less than "_", but letters after "c" are "bigger" than "_"? In the first case it breaks auto_* words with autosport word which does not contain _ and it seems strange to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any answer about sort order requires knowing your current locale, `LC_ALL` and `LC_COLLATE` settings.

Comment: If you were to look up "auto_design" in a dictionary, wouldn't you look between "autobahn" and "autodial"?

Comment: Ergo, it does not sort lexicographically. Lexicographic sorts have limited utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character order used by `sort` is provided by your current locale settings.

If you want a minimum of surprises, and don't need locale-specific character ordering, set `LC_COLLATE=C` in your environment. This can be scoped to a single command like so:

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort test.txt
```

See [the glibc documentation on locales](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locales.html) for more information on how locales can be configured.

---

To give an example of "locale-specific collation order" -- in Estonian, `ö` sorts after `w`, whereas it's more typical for `ö` to sort somewhere between `n` and `p`... but in a pure ASCII sort, such characters follow after the entire `a-z` set in full.

Comment: Thanks. Can you say how it sorts when this env variable is empty? Comparing by what?

Comment: If `LC_COLLATE` is empty, then `LC_ALL` is checked. If no collation order is set anywhere in the system, the default is `C` (or its synonym `POSIX`), but a modern operating system will almost always set it _somewhere_.

Comment: Setting `LANG` will also impact collation order, if `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_ALL` are not set.